# Missing dependencies in "testing Java persistence" guide

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian

I am studying Arquillian platform. To do examples I use Eclipse. I first successfully followed 

http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/
and after that, I tried to do code examples in
http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/
but I am having library dependency troubles:

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
```

are not recognized by Eclipse.

This is the **pom.xml** file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I take it you've executed `mvn eclipse:eclipse`? Also the class  `org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment` is contained in the following artifact: org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api. This doesn't appear to be defined explicitly in your pom, you could try adding it to see if it helps.

Comment: I imported the project with maven to eclipse, and I solved the problem with the answer n.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arquillian BOM should be present as a `dependency` in the `dependencyManagement` section of your POM, and not as an ordinary dependendcy, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  ...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Note the use of the Arquillian BOM and the `arquillian-junit-container` dependency (whose version is specified via the BOM). Not using the Arquillian BOM would require you to specify the version of the `arquillian-junit-container` dependency. The other required depdendencies are `junit:junit` and an Arquillian container adapter (in your case, the Weld embedded container adapter).